# C# Windows Service - Set service login Issue

Tags: windows, winforms, windows-services

I'm building a windows service that retrieves information about different hardware, and after that it stores the information in a database, right now that part is done and im trying to install that service in different computers, and i wanted to know if the little window that pops up during the installation, called Set Service login, is possible to set some default values in those textboxes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the Visual Studio Installer you could try this:
View the code of the processInstaller and go into  InitializeComponent() methode.
There you can set the following properties for an existing local account:

```
this.servicename_processInstaller.Password = "xxxxx";
this.servicename_processInstaller.Username = ".\\localServiceUserAccount";
```

This prevent to prompt the window.